# Disable zoom on input focus in Android smartphone

Tags: android, css, input

i have a issue in my Android page on input focus, i can't disable auto-zoom
only in (orientation: portrait) :

http://ufficio.web-project.it/smlapalma/akenta/invia-scusa.html

I have already try this codes:

meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=0'

or

input:focus { font-size: 16px!important}

but nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Guido

Answer (score 1):

This would be the right `meta`-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

But, this won't solve your problem because this meta tag doesn't change the size of your sites components. Let's say you have a `<div>` with the width of 1200px, the user's browser will view it 1200px wide.

I looked at your website, and the problem lies in the foundation of your CSS. You are using `px` a lot, where you might want to use `%`. If you use percentage, you will see that your site adjusts to the screen size. You should also use `em` as unit for font size instead of px. My tip is to avoid `px`-units as much as possible.

But of course, this means you will have to change your entire CSS, which is much work. But eventually this will solve your problem.

Comment: no, i'm sorry... i added the meta-tag but don't work the input fields, please check now